# VS Code Extension installation errors

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, failed-installation

I'm new to python. Im taking Mosh Hamedani's course. When Im installing extensions in VS Code I'm getting errors. The extensions I have installed are 'atuopep8', 'pylint' and 'code runner'.

Can someone please interpret what is happening here? Thank you very much.

```
2023-11-16 12:05:28.009 [info] [Info  - 12:05:28 PM] (596) Pylance language server 2023.11.10 (pyright 088ebaa5) starting
2023-11-16 12:05:28.010 [info] [Info  - 12:05:28 PM] (596) Server root directory: C:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.11.10\dist
2023-11-16 12:05:28.017 [info] [Info  - 12:05:28 PM] (596) Starting service instance "HelloWorld"
2023-11-16 12:05:28.073 [info] [Info  - 12:05:28 PM] (596) Setting pythonPath for service "HelloWorld": "C:\Users\ross.williams\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
2023-11-16 12:05:28.074 [info] [Info  - 12:05:28 PM] (596) Setting environmentName for service "HelloWorld": "3.12.0 (global)"
2023-11-16 12:05:28.309 [info] [Info  - 12:05:28 PM] (596) Assuming Python version 3.12
2023-11-16 12:05:28.503 [info] [Info  - 12:05:28 PM] (596) Found 1 source file
2023-11-16 12:05:29.040 [info] ERROR: The process "27216" not found.

2023-11-16 12:20:01.616 [info] [Error - 12:20:01 PM] Server process exited with code 1.
2023-11-16 12:20:01.616 [info] [Error - 12:20:01 PM] Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted.
2023-11-16 12:20:01.616 [info] [Error - 12:20:01 PM] Handling connection close failed
2023-11-16 12:20:01.616 [info] TypeError: e.clear is not a function
    at _.cleanUp (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2412859)
    at _.handleConnectionClosed (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2417283)
    at _.handleConnectionClosed (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2578252)
    at c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2416709
    at o.invoke (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2363387)
    at s.fire (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2364152)
    at te (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2349784)
    at o.invoke (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2363387)
    at s.fire (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2364152)
    at d.fireClose (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2372012)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\ross.williams\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\out\client\extension.js:2:2384364)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug in the pylance extension has been reported: [*Connection to server got closed. Server will not be restarted*](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5086).

The prerelease version of the extension has the fix for this problem.